# Rule Interaction and the Organization of a Grammar

Tags: grammar, resource-request

Apologies for not posing a proper question, but I'd like to find a copy of *Rule Interaction and the Organization of a Grammar*, by Geoffrey K. Pullum (1979), which I believe to be his doctoral thesis. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Ask your university librarian, they now how to find literature and how to bring it to you.

Answer (score 1):

It was [published in the US](https://books.google.com/books/about/Rule_Interaction_and_the_Organization_of.html?id=mBJtAAAAIAAJ), and can be acquired through standard interlibrary loan sources.